# Error in c program using fedora?

Tags: gcc, fedora

[king@localhost ~]$ gcc -oer temp.cpp
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

what is this Error ??
what is the solution for this..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile a C++ file with a C compiler. You want to use `g++ -oer temp.cpp` not `gcc -oer temp.cpp`.

Comment: or, if it is a C program, rename the file to be temp.c; note that if you do have a C++ program, you will need to install g++ (which I think is called gcc-c++ on Fedora)